# Auto numerate MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

Is there any mysql query, to update a table and set numbers starting from 1?
For example, the table "item" has 100000 rows, the query would just update first row and set id ="1", next to 2, 3, 4 etc.

Comment: You want to update which `column`? better post the table structure code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE item MODIFY id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

If you have id in your item table.
But it will show error on id column having duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

add auto increment column (INT) and it should do what you want

Comment: you can del existed row and rename new to the name of old.
then if you like you can move it at the beginning, add indexes, etc

Answer (score 0):

Is there already a primary key in the table? If not then create one with `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

This would do the job done.

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table`
ADD COLUMN `id_primary`  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_primary`);
```

**Note:** Changing an existing column to `primary key AUTO_INCREMENT` would raise error if that column contains duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Given this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from posts;
+------+--------+----------+
| id   | userid | category |
+------+--------+----------+
| NULL |      1 | a        |
| NULL |      1 | b        |
| NULL |      1 | c        |
| NULL |      2 | a        |
| NULL |      1 | a        |
+------+--------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This code

```
use sandbox;
update  posts p,(select @rn:=0) rn
set         id=(@rn:=@rn+1)
where   1 = 1;
```

Results in

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from posts;
+------+--------+----------+
| id   | userid | category |
+------+--------+----------+
|    1 |      1 | a        |
|    2 |      1 | b        |
|    3 |      1 | c        |
|    4 |      2 | a        |
|    5 |      1 | a        |
+------+--------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```